# mod_rewrite: Convert Folders into Query Params

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

everyone. I would like to simulate a user system like Youtube's. For example, if you type youtube.com/ it will take you to their profile. I have a similar thing running currently. If you go to example.com/user/ the mod_rewrite will change the url to example.com/user/?channel=. This works correctly, but I don't want the visual of the URL changed. Is there any way I can still pass the username to PHP while having human readible URLS? Here's a current example of my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /user/
RewriteRule ^(.+) ?channel=$1 [R]
```

Comment: Try pointing to the full path `RewriteRule .+ /user/?channel=$0`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can: Don't use `[R]` -- it's [an "external" redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) to the specified location.

Answer (score 0):

Are these rules what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^user/? /user/?channel=
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z0-9-_]+)/? /user/?channel=$1
```

And the PHP tips that you're looking for:

```
<?php
echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```

Comment: @Brett What did you tried to visit? Maybe the URL that you're visiting is remapped on a **404** page that couldn't be found. Could you please link your site here?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you want this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^ /user/?channel%1
```